# How Do I Use a Date (in the MM-dd-yyyy format) in a URL in an MVC Application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have an MVC2 project that has a route in the RegisterRoutes method as follows:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "PrettyUrl",
    "Airplanes/{query}/{page}",
    new { controller = "Airplanes", action = "Details", query ="", page = 0 }
);
```

Currently, the URL for a GET looks like **`Airplanes/va123-va234/1`** - I would like to add a date like: **`Airplanes/va123-va234/10-10-2010/1`** but I can't figure out how to get the route to map the date to this format.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a parameter for date

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "PrettyUrl",
    "Airplanes/{query}/{date}/{page}",
    new { controller = "Airplanes", action = "Details", query ="", page = 0, 
          date = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

In your controller method, make sure you take in a `date` parameter.

```
    public ActionResult Details(string query, string date, int page) {
        var newDate = DateTime.Parse(date);
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't work.  I end up with a URL that looks like this:
`Airplanes/22222-22300/11/29/2010 00%3a00%3a00`.  To keep the "/" in the date from screwing up the url, and to keep the time out of the url, I want to *format* it in the url as MM-dd-yyyy

Comment: Can you show the code where you call the method, Html.ActionLink, ControllerAction etc...